# Accordion doesn't collapse using <apex:repeat in a VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, accordion

I was looking to implement the accordion in visualforce page and found this [link](http://blogforce9.blogspot.com/2013/04/visualforce-accordion-component-easy.html) and i like it and when I try to implement on my page having `<apex:Repeat>` then the accordion does not collapse/close so I tried without using the `<apex:repeat>` than it work as it shown here in [demo](http://%20http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/jQueryAccordionDemo)

I have created very simple page with the use of `apex:repeat` and if you just copy and paste the code in your org, you will see that it does not collapse when you click on the header of the accordion.

PS: there is dependency and you need to have the components which you can download from [here](http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ProjectDetail?id=a0290000007rdIr)

VF Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="repeatCon">
  <apex:form >  
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Accordion" subtitle="Accordion" />
    <apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
    <c:Accordion >
        <c:AccordionSection title="Section "> 
           <apex:pageBlock title="Page block" mode="edit " id="pb">
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="my title" columns="1" id="rt"  > 
                    some text here...
                </apex:pageBlockSection>   
            </apex:pageBlock> 
            </c:AccordionSection>
    </c:Accordion>
     </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public class repeatCon { 

    public String[] getStrings() {
      return new String[]{'ONE','TWO','THREE'};

    } 
}
```

in order to work the sample page you need the following coponents and [resources](http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ProjectDetail?id=a0290000007rdIr):

Comment: Not sure if I have an answer, but I'll take a peek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each c:Accordion area *always* has one section open. The way you've written your code results in many c:Accordion elements, which in turns keeps all of them open. Simply move the apex:repeat inside the c:Accordion, and it works as expected:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="repeatCon">
  <apex:form >  
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Accordion" subtitle="Accordion" />
    <c:Accordion >
    <apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
        <c:AccordionSection title="Section "> 
           <apex:pageBlock title="Page block" mode="edit " id="pb">
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="my title" columns="1" id="rt"  > 
                    some text here...
                </apex:pageBlockSection>   
            </apex:pageBlock> 
            </c:AccordionSection>
     </apex:repeat>
    </c:Accordion>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: one question came to my mind, is that possible to click on the current Accordion header and close? so in other words all collapse ?

Comment: @NickKahn In the Accordion component, lines 20-24, we just need to add a line of code: `function initAccordion(){
            $j( ".custAaccordion" ).accordion({ 
                header: ".custHeader",
                collapsible: true
            });
        }`. Perhaps we could recommend to the original author that the collapsible attribute be available in the component's definition.

Comment: how did you find out `collapsible` property? it did work but just curious to know.. .thanks again

Comment: @NickKahn I started by looking at the source for the component, and deduced that they were most likely using the [jQuery UI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) plugin, checked the docs for that plugin, then tested it in my dev org. Luckily it was the standard plugin, because the code's been minified, so I would have had trouble figuring it out if it wasn't.

Comment: great tip... I will keep in mind..